# Проблема с установкой обоев на телефон

Tags: android, kotlin

Сделал приложение на андроид для смены обоев на телефоне. Когда запускаю приложение на эмуляторе в Android Studio при нажатии кнопки `Set Wallpaper` (устанавливает выбранное изображение в качестве обоев)

Все работает отлично т.е. обои устанавливаются прекрасно, по размеру, как надо. А вот когда это же действие я выполняю на реальном устройстве обои устанавливаются не правильно(они увеличиваются в размере и на экране лишь кусок от полного изображения).

[image]

Функция которая устанавливает обои

```
private fun setWallpaper() {
    //Change Text and Disable Button
    detail_set_btn.isEnabled = false
    detail_set_btn.text = "Wallpaper Set"
    detail_set_btn.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorDark, null))

    val bitmap: Bitmap = detail_image.drawable.toBitmap()
    val task: SetWallpaperTask = SetWallpaperTask(requireContext(),bitmap)
    task.execute(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вид картинки в качестве обоев определяет не программист (он не может устанавливать свои рамки или пожелания, поэтому понятия правильно или не правильно здесь неуместны), а непосредственно программа Launcher, на одном устройстве это может быть так на другом по другому, на одном скроллироваться, на другом нет, добро пожаловать в мир программирования для Андроид.
Если же вы хотите чтобы все выглядело исключительно как вы хотите, то придется использоваться движок Живых обоев и самому заниматься отображением картинки.